# Freely Available Web Services/APIs

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm building some Silverlight applications in my spare time, and I wanted find some freely available web services or APIs that I can call. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html) (there are a lot of Gogle APIs, to tell the truth) and the [Stack Overflow API](https://stackapps.com/) to name a couple.

Hmm... let's add some more:

- [Stack Overflow API](https://stackapps.com/)
- [Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html)
- [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)
- [Yahoo Maps API](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html)
- [Bing Maps API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980922.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, could you send me the links?

Comment: @ash 2010: links added. There are a lot more; a simple Google search should reveal many.

Answer (score 5):

There is a massive list at Yahoo, exposed via [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) (yahoo query language). It even exposes sites that do not have web services as web services.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Answer (score 1):

WSDL Web service directories:

- http://www.service-repository.com/
- http://www.xmethods.net/

Comment: In fact; I'm following this question explicitly because of this answer.

Comment: Hey, I honestly just did a "public web service" Web search. I think we need to start the corresponding Wikipedia page, too

Comment: Link any favorites you find!!

Comment: Weather: http://www.service-repository.com/client/calloperations?wsdlURL=http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx%3Fwsdl

Comment: IP GeoLocation: http://www.service-repository.com/client/calloperations?wsdlURL=http://www.ecubicle.net/iptocountry.asmx%3Fwsdl

Answer (score 0):

There'a a whole website which specializes in just such services, though not only free ones:

> [ProgrammableWeb - Mashups, APIs, and the Web as Platform](http://www.programmableweb.com)

They have a tagline "Keeping you up to date with APIs, mashups and the Web as platform."

As of today they claim to list 7,144 APIs and 6,759 Mashups.

(I'm not affiliated in any way but I often stumble across it when searching for web services and has made various useful discoveries thanks to them.)